# how to use specific python executable in teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cicd

I am trying to control the python version in teamcity build step(I have few versionsin my regression system)

but 'python executable:' is greyed out.

is someone encountered with such issue ?
teamcity version is 2020.1

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to change the python executable if you don't specify a 'kind'

Comment: i tried to check all types of kind but none of them expose the option to change the executable